# What precisely is a construct in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, execution, language-construct

As I learn JavaScript I've been looking around the web and seen numerous references to **constructs** in Javascript, but I can't seem to find a complete definition of what they are and what they are not, especially in the context of Javascript.

For instance, in 'Similar Questions' I see links that lead to an example featuring the following code:

In [What is this construct in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-this-construct-in-javascript):

```
(function () {

})();
```

From what I understand this is a construct, but what are they defined by?

Comment: @dbaseman, read the question more carefully

Comment: @u1sonderzug, Is there anything you are still confused about here?

Answer (score 13):

Construct is a generic term referring to an arbitrary aggregate of code in a specific formation.  It is not a javascript-specific term.

Basically, it can apply to anything.  So, while the code you referenced is a construct known as a self invoking anonymous function, `var x = "hello world";` is a construct known as a variable declaration and assignment.

Comment: In JavaScript, could it be said that anything that ends in a ; is a construct? Up until the ; ?

Comment: Anything is a construct.  A keyword is a construct. A value literal is a construct.  The semicolon is not necessary.  You are overthinking this.

Comment: But if var x = "hello world"; is a construct, based on what you said that 'Anything is a construct' does it mean that 'x' or just 'world' is a construct? Doesn't it refer to a line of code somehow? I know this probably sounds ridiculous - but I really am not 100% clear here.

Comment: Yes.  x is a variable.  The "world" is a string literal.  Variables and string literals are both constructs in javascript.  The definition of construct in terms of javascript is the same definition you will find in a standard english dictionary

Comment: "Statement" is the term for the language constructs that end with `;`.

Answer (score 6):

A *"[language construct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_construct)"* is the full term you're looking for. According to the linked definition:

> A language construct is a syntactically allowable part of a program that may be formed from one or more lexical tokens in accordance with the rules of a programming language.

So it's any valid segment of written code that follows the rules of the language. It's a generalisation of words like "expression", "statement", "function argument list", "assignment statement", "keyword", "function definition", etc. that each define a series of tokens to look for and what they will mean in the rules of the language. The code of a completed program is *constructed* with them.

Comment: "It's a generalisation of words like..." is why this is the winner for me. Makes it clear that "construct" is a meta concept, not a coding pattern.

Answer (score 0):

From the Scripting Reference in [MASTERING HTML4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0782125247) by Deborah and Eric Ray:

> Constructs are the structures that you can use in a JavaScript to control the flow of the script

They go on as to alphabetically list ALL such a controls which include Break, Comment, If, If else....
So a **construct** is a very specific term definition in JavaScript used to name and encompass all the statements (structures) that control the flow of a script.